# Renewing Long-Expired British Passport

Tags: united-kingdom, passports, us-residents

- I was born in England, 1984
- Currently have Canadian Passport and reside in the United States
- I am a permanent resident in the US (Green Card)
- I have a British Birth Certificate

Please find out what the most convenient process for renewal is, how long it takes approx, any forms that need to be filled out, and whether I need to send my CAnadian passport in or not.

Comment: Have you looked at this https://www.gov.uk/overseas-passports?

Comment: Out of interest, why do you want a British passport?  It looks likely that in a few months time it won't get you into the EU any more easily than a Canadian passport.

Comment: Sorry.  Just noticed that your title says you have already had a British passport, so you are clearly entitled.

Answer (score 4):

The forms, prices and application details you need if you’re a British national and you want to renew or apply for a British passport from overseas are available via this page https://www.gov.uk/overseas-passports

It’s not possible to answer your detailed questions about the process because the Gov.uk page requires the input of various pieces of data personal to your circumstances in order to determine the correct application route.

Comment: This is the most convenient process. Otherwise, we would have to keep asking the OP questions like "Has your last British passport been lost?".